# Notepad ++ Regular Expression Replacement

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've got a big XML file and I should modify a tag.

Original:

```
<MyTag>13/19/59/70/68/32'</MyTag>'
```

What I want with regular expression:

```
<MyTag>13,19,59,70,68,32</MyTag>
```

That could be pretty easy if I'd got each time the same quantity of number but I could have 8 number or 5 or 6 or less.

How can I do that in one time?

Comment: Please check whether the text is displayed correctly. I tried my best to guess what you want and edited your post, but I am not sure whether it is your original text.

Comment: notepad++ regex is is not that powerful. Please check this link for some help http://markantoniou.blogspot.ca/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in the comments, Notepad++'s regexes don't seem to be powerful enough to make that replace. In general, I don't think bare regex replacement isn't powerful enough for this replacement, you could at most get `13/19/59/70/68/32` in a capture group, and perform the `/` to `,` replace on that string by other means. That's why maybe I'd consider using another tool you are proficient in (perl, java, whatever) instead.

Using notepad++, I'd go for a normal replace first, to change all occurrences of `'</MyTag>'` to `</MyTag>`, and then a regex replace with this regular expression: `(\d+)/`. The replace should be  `\1,`. Clicking on *Replace all* should replace all occurrences.

If you wanted to avoid replacing digits separated by `/` in other tags, maybe you could use this regular expression `<MyTag>(.*)(\d+)/(.*)</MyTag>` and replace it with `<MyTag>\1\2,\3</MyTag>`. This replace will have to be executed N times, so you might be interested in recording a macro or similar if you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

**IT IS POSSIBLE TO DO IN ONE REGEXP.**

Search for:

```
/([0-9]+)('(<){1}/(MyTag>){1}')?
```

Replace with:

```
,\1\3\4
```